# Can I use path parameters in react-router basename route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I found a similar [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196448/can-i-set-a-base-route-in-react-router) and this [unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323993/wildcard-in-react-router-4-basename), however, what do you do when you need a dynamic path (path parameter)?

Like `/calendar/:year/:month/:day/event` where it could be, for example, `/calendar/11/4/21/event`

Comment: edit: wait! --- reread question.... checking ~exactly how you've written it https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params~

Comment: actually I don't think I totally understand your question. you want dynamic paths, but also using a basename?

Answer (score 3):

The `basename` that you can pass to a router (e.g. `<BrowserRouter basename='/thing'>`) is not dynamic. You should think of the basename as the static path to the root directory where your app is located (although this might not be a literal path since you're most likely using a dynamic server).

Occasionally I have seen requests for dynamic basenames, usually when someone has language sections of their site (`example.com/en/about` and `example.com/zh/about`). The usual reason for wanting to include this information in the `basename` is so that it doesn't have to be included in URIs. However, the `basename` isn't supposed to contain information about the route; any data that isn't going to be the same for every single route in your application should not be part of the basename.